# What happens to my loot if I dismiss Lydia and hire Stenvar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing the anniversary edition of Skyrim and am only about 100 hours into the game. I have had Lydia for a long time. Now, I have the option to buy Stenvars services, causing me to need to dismiss Lydia. What happens to all of my loot she's carrying? Where does she do? Back to Breezehome or Dragons Reach?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Regarding the "Is Stenvar a good upgrade from Lydia?" you are asking too many questions in one post, making this closeable as too broad. You may want to delete that part, and maybe ask another question itself.

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? [Do followers lose items when replaced with companions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/51111/4797) | [Can dismissed companions be trusted with my loot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/37293/4797)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had to leave Lydia in order to use another follower to sacrifice to Boethiah.

I found her at [Breezehome](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Breezehome), the house we own in Whiterun, since she is the housecarl.
And she still had my loot in her inventory.