# In Skyrim Lydia's starting gear is gone

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I reached level 41 (don't know if that had anything to do with it or not), I was thinking of giving Lydia some different armor, and when I went into her inventory list all her steel armor was gone: gauntlets, boots, chest armor, everything!  She had all the ebony stuff I had given her, but not the steel.  Anyone else have this happen?

Comment: related, possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45933/problem-with-followers-maxed-on-carrying-capacity-but-not-carrying-that-much

Comment: pretty sure the default character gear is usually hidden (and unremovable).

Answer (score 5):

Default NPC gear is not viewable without mods.

You can transfer gear and equipment to followers and they will automatically upgrade if it is better for them to use.

A related topic is here [companions and armour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36994/my-companion-wont-wear-her-armor?rq=1)