# why is reversed pick pocketing a crime?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whenever I get bored I tend to pickpockets everyone in sight. So, after I pretty much stripped every guard in the city down to his underwear, I noticed that my inventory was kinda full.

So I picked a nice fellow of which I thought: "That guy could use 17 complete sets of armor."
After successfully putting 5 sets of armor in his pocket and trying to give another, a (half-naked) guard came to me and said that I had *committed a crime against Skyrim and its people*.

What crime did I commit?
 (Ignoring the massive pick pocketing crime, 'cause nobody saw that or was paid not to see it)

**EDIT:**

Since this is not really seen as correct SE question I adjust my question a bit.
**Is there a legal way to give 17 set of armor to somebody?**

Comment: I imagine if you saw someone cramming suits of armour into someone's pockets on the street without them noticing, you'd tell the authorities too...

Comment: This is a "why did they design it that way question", which is unanswerable and not a good fit for Arqade.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112851/what-will-happen-with-items-i-put-into-someones-inventory-during-pickpocket/112858#112858 @SirDuckduck Gameplay-wise, [it's probably because you can hurt or even kill someone thru reverse-pickpocketing.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/112858/4797)

Answer (score 3):

Trespassing onto someone elses property (your hand, in their pocket).

Comment: In that case you should get arrested the moment you look in there pockets. And the people of Skyrim never made objection to me trespassing onto there property.

Comment: It became against the law after it was determined that the average citizen of Skyrim would not give a second thought to drinking random bottles of liquid that mysteriously materialized on their person.